# Programming mouse buttons on a non-programmable mouse

Tags: mouse

I bought a TeckNet WM289 Gaming mouse, but need to reprogram the 'fire' button, which does a very fast double click. This mouse is not programmable so doesn't come with any software. Is there any way to still reprogram the button to do something else than double click?

Comment: Are you on windows?

Comment: If you're on Windows, [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/) may be useful.

Comment: Yeah, I'm on windows, I'd need to get the exact timings of the double click first to do anything though.

Comment: Ok I was able to get the timings, but I have no idea how to detect that its a triple click with the exact timings while putting no delay on the normal left click if it is not.